# What should I do with question, that moved significantly from when it started?

Tags: discussion

I had a question on SO that noone replied to.

By investigating the issue more and more, I found out that the real reason of the problem lies completely elsewhere than I initially asked.

Should I completely rewrite the question, or close this one and make a new one?
The question itself is here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416051/java-program-with-eclipselink-toplink-runs-incredibly-slow-with-java-web-start

I found out that it has, in fact, nothing to do with TopLink/EclipseLink.

Answer (score 2):

I would close and open a new question, referencing the original so people have context

Comment: hm, I found out I can't close question just by myself

Comment: @Karel, you can always flag it for moderator attention if you really want it closed. If it a real question that may help others I would just leave it there, and remember to accept an answer